# How to generate build.xml ant in Jdeveloper?

Tags: java, xml, ant, jdeveloper

I'm trying to make a jar from my project and i need to use Ant...

I'm trying to generate the build.xml through :

"Project -> New -> Ant -> BuildFile from Project"

In all tutorials that i saw... all of them recomends to check an option "Include Packaging Tasks (uses OjDeploy)" but this option is disabled, and i can't check this option.

The build.xml is generated, but not appears to be functional...i try to run it, but nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: how are you running it?  "ant -f "filepath"  "target"?  Show the logs

Comment: i'm running through JDeveloper... through ant icon. This xml appears to be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably options like those get grayed out if the corresponding feature is not added in the project properties, so be liberal with the features and add them in project properties.
HTH